# How to remove status messages from admin theme?

Tags: 8, status-messages

I am working with Drupal 8. I have enabled "[Seven](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/themes/seven-theme)" as admin theme. When I have added an image with high resolution I am getting 2 error messages at a time(screenshot). I want to hide "green" colored status message from this particular page. I have tried with `hook_page_attachments(array &$attachments)` in my custom module to include the css for admin theme.

But it is not working. How to solve this issue?

[image].

Answer (score 2):

hook_page_attachments is not the correct hook. You want to implement hook_preprocess_HOOK, like the example below.

There are some caveats with this fix, especially if your site will be localized to other languages, see the comments within the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 * Implements hook_preprocess_status_messages().
 *
 * @param $variables
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_status_messages(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['message_list']['status'])) {
    $status_messages = $variables['message_list']['status'];
    $dummy_message_parameter_1 = '_parameter_1_';
    $dummy_message_parameters =       [
      '%dimensions' => $dummy_message_parameter_1,
      '%new_width' => 0,
      '%new_height' => 0,
    ];
    // The message could change eventually, but it is unlikely.
    // This logic *could brake* in a some language translations, if the %dimensions string is not the first parameter.
    $file_resize_message = t('The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions of %dimensions pixels. The new dimensions of the resized image are %new_widthx%new_height pixels.', $dummy_message_parameters);
    // $file_resize_message_start is the part of the message that won't vary.
    $file_resize_message_start =strtok((string)$file_resize_message, $dummy_message_parameter_1); ;
    foreach ($status_messages as $delta => $message) {
      if (strpos((string)$message, $file_resize_message_start) !== FALSE) {
        // The next commented line still leaves a green area
        // unset($variables['message_list']['status'][$delta]);
        // Removing all messages, the side effect is that you could be
        // missing on some relevant messages
        unset($variables['message_list']['status']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The message is set in the function `file_validate_image_resolution` at core/modules/file/file.module:447 (as of version 8.6.0-dev)

There is a good explanation about the hook implementation at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788080/remove-default-message-in-drupal-8)

Comment: It is working.Now the message is hidden.But the green section is still there.Is it possible to hide this?Thank you.

Comment: @salu – With CSS, yes.

Comment: @leymannx: I want to remove this from admin side.And my admin theme is "seven".So how can i add css?

Comment: @salu I just updated the code to remove all messages, I don't think would be easy use CSS here. The green area is innocuous, maybe consider leaving it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd fix this with CSS. But maybe this specific message can't be targeted specifically. Although I'd definitely try that first.

And then have a look at [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages).

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message
>   is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users.
>   However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages
>   sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module
>   gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out
>   messages shown to the end users.
>
> Features
>
> - Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
> - Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> - Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> - Disable all filtering for specific users.
> - Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> - Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> - Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

Comment: I have already tried with this module.But it is not working